# Vanilla JS – Get element location (in percent) based on parent container

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get a link's location on click relative to the parent container in order to see where the item was clicked (i.e `top`, `middle` or `bottom`)

The problem I have is that the HTML structure is like this:

```
<div class="article-content">
  <h1>heading</h1>
  <img src="../img/img1.jpg" />
  <div class="section">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<a href="#">Link 1</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<a href="#">Link 2</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<a href="#">Link 3</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Once a link is clicked, I would like to get the position of the link in relation to the `.article-content`-container. This is for an analytics implementation so **vanilla js is required**.

The solution I tried so far does not account for the selected parent element (`.article-content`).

```
function getScrollPos(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
  var parent = document.querySelector('.article-content');
  var scrollPercent = 100*(this.offsetTop / document.querySelector('.article-content').scrollHeight);
  console.log(scrollPercent);
    if (scrollPercent > 0 && scrollPercent < 33) {
    console.log('top');
  } else if (scrollPercent > 33 && scrollPercent < 66) {
    console.log('middle');
  } else {
    console.log('bottom');
  }
}

document.querySelectorAll('.article-content a').forEach(function(el) {
    el.addEventListener('click', getScrollPos);
})
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lcfsq6xm)

So my question is: can I get the `offsetTop` based on the offset to the container-element rather than the direct parent?

Comment: You can use [`getClientBoundingRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) to get the coordinates of parent and child.

Comment: It sounds like what you want is a function to take the button clicked, the `<a>`, and find the closest Parent element that is a `.article-content`. [This article](https://gomakethings.com/how-to-get-the-closest-parent-element-with-a-matching-selector-using-vanilla-javascript/) can show you how to create a plain Javascript function to find the closest matching ancestor element